# gnu screen frozen sessions

Tags: gnu-screen

I have frequently had gnu screen sessions freeze (no keyboard input is accepted) and become unrecoverable.  This usually happens when typing fast or interrupting a task.  However,

- the screen itself is active: `ctrl-a [` still allows scrollback.
- Scrolling is still active: if I send the shell session `kill -INT <pid>`, a `^C` appears on screen.
- `ctrl Q` and `ctrl-a q`, which are [commonly suggested solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367669/the-gnu-screen-is-unresponsive-seems-blocked), have no effect.
- `screen -S <session_name> -p 1 -X stuff "ls^M"` has no effect (I would expect it to run `ls` in the selected session; it works on other screens)

Is there anything else I can try to recover screens that freeze like this?

For some further context: I'm running slurm `srun` interactive jobs in `screen` windows on this machine and then spawning background child processes, so I don't want to kill the window (doing so terminates the `srun` job).  My current solution is just to regard the window as dead until the `srun` job runs out of time, which sucks because I'm down a numbered screen tab for weeks.

Comment: It is not a common behaviour, so I would check non-standard settings on your machine. On the other hand, you say it is not freezing (e.g. with scrolling). So how do you know your screen session is freezing? Could you check where (which function) it freeze? (note process may use buffered output, or job control inside will block, or maybe it is huge swapping). You should investigate more. Or maybe just incompatible terminal settings

Comment: I can't give keyboard input of any sort - ctrl-c, enter, etc. all do nothing.  The incompatible terminal settings sound promising - could you point me in a direction (e.g., other SE questions) to look for that?